# WshShell.Run always returns exit code 0

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsh

I've executed WScript on windows Server 2012 R2 and WSH version 5.8.

I've called `WshShell.Run(command.bat, 1, true)`, but it always returns exit code `0`.
The command.bat return exit code `1`. But the `WshShell.Run(command.bat, 1, true)` return `0`.

How can I return the correct exit code `1`?

Answer (score 0):

If your `command.bat` executes succesfully it will return 0 if it has an error it will return 1.

If I understand your question you want the WScript to return the return value of the `command.bat` to that end you can do this:

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
var bat_return_value = WshShell.Run("command.bat", 1, true)
WScript.Quit(bat_return_value)
```